# What are the well known Webkit-specific pseudo-elements?

Tags: css, webkit, pseudo-element

As I was poking around, looking for cool, easy web design styles, I found [this interesting article](http://www.webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/), and it just happened to use webkit, which is in Chrome, which I am experimenting with.  I also found [this article](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Styling%20Form%20Controls), which is just as cool as the first one.  So, my question is, are there any other well-known webkit-specific pseudo elements that I should be aware of?  They make making cool web applications easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*the only good source on subject is webkit source* ..

Check [html.css](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css) and [CSSSelector.cpp](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/CSSSelector.cpp)
and if you have spare time search through their root folder - http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/ - as there can still be more of them.

Just keep in mind, - our browsers rarely use latest engine versions and there are signinfican differences between Chrome and Safari ;)

Comment: Thank you for the links!  I will be using these a bunch in the future.